# Does Postman auto converts a number to string when using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to understand how the regular expression works in postman. I think I read somewhere that regular expression only works for string. So say I have response of a number type, I am expecting my test below to fail but its not failing.

```
pm.test("Using regular expression for integer", function() {
var apiReply = pm.response.json();

pm.expect(/^[\d]+$/.test(apiReply.response.data )).to.be.true;
```

});

**Sample tests:**

`{ "response" : { "data" : "999" }}` => I am expecting to passed. This is fine.

`{ "response" : { "data" : 999 }}` => I am expecting to fail but it is passing

Does Postman auto converts a number to string because I am using a regular expression in my test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Postman does not do anything here, JavaScript does.

And yes, one of the first actions taken is calling `ToString()` method on the argument passed to `RegExp.prototype.test()`. You can read about it [here in ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexp.prototype.test).